# Why is Copy-Item overwriting destination files by default?

Tags: powershell

The behaviour I would expect from the code below is:

1. Grab a list of the files in the source directory.
2. Loop through and copy each file to the backup destination, only if it does not already exist.

   ```
   if (!(Test-Path C:\Folder\Destination)) {
      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path C:\Folder\Destination
   }

   $originalfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path  "C:\Folder\Source"
   $originalfiles

   foreach ($file in $originalfiles) {
       Write-Host
       Write-Host File Name: -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
       Write-Host $file.Name
       Write-Host File Path: -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
       Write-Host $file.FullName

       $src = $file.FullName
       $dest = "C:\Folder\Destination\$($file.Name)"

       Copy-Item $src $dest
   }
   ```

I would have thought that the `Copy-Item` cmdlet defaults to NOT overwrite, unless you specify the `-Force` flag. This is the behaviour I have seen in the past when I originally encountered situations where I did want to overwrite.

Also, I thought it may be the introduction of the `foreach` loop but I tried the copy command, on it's own, with hardcoded paths for a single file, and it is still the same.

Should I restart my IDE, or is it a mistake I have overlooked?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item).

> **`-Force`**
>
> Indicates that this cmdlet copies items that can't otherwise be changed, such as copying over a read-only file or alias.

The default behavior for `Copy-Item` is to replace existing items. The `-Force` switch is only to enforce replacement if for instance the destination file has the readonly attribute set.

You can use `-Confirm` to get prompted before `Copy-Item` performs the operation, or you can use `-WhatIf` to see what the cmdlet would do.

Comment: The wording of the documentation quote actually suggests that `-Force` affects the _copied_ (_source_) item, not the _destination_ item. Are you saying -Force applies to the destination item here? If so, we can file a pull request for that documentation to be updated.

Answer (score 17):

Old one, but I found a short expression that does that:

```
Copy-Item (Join-Path $dir_from "*") $dir_to -Exclude (Get-ChildItem $dir_to)
```

It copies all files from `$dir_from` to `$dir_to` but not (the -Exclude part) the files with names that are already in `$dir_to`

Comment: This is the only one that has worked for me in terms of copying and overwriting existing files with the same names.    For those not familiar with Powershell, $dir_from and $dir_to should be defined in quotes.  For example, $dir_to = "C:\users\..."

Comment: This is useless if someone wants to use `-recurse`.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be the expected behaviour of `Copy-Item` to copy an item to the destination even if it already exists in destination. I suggest to test, if the destination file path exists and only copy the file if it does not yet exist.

```
$destinationPath = 'C:\tryout\destination';
if (!(Test-Path $destinationPath)) 
{
   New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $destinationPath;
}

$sourcePath = 'C:\tryout\source';
$originalfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath;
$originalfiles;

foreach ($file in $originalfiles) 
{
    Write-Host;
    Write-Host File Name: -ForegroundColor DarkYellow;
    Write-Host $file.Name;
    Write-Host File Path: -ForegroundColor DarkYellow;
    Write-Host $file.FullName;

    $src = $file.FullName;
    $dest = "C:\tryout\destination\$($file.Name)";

    if (!(Test-Path $dest))
    {
        Copy-Item $src -Destination $dest;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't account for when someone wants to use `-recurse`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version of your code to copy files **recursively** only when they don't exist in target location. It creates subfolders if needed. It doesn't create empty folders; if you need them, remove `-File` from `Get-ChildItem`.

```
$srcDirPath = "C:\SourceDir"
$destDirPath = "C:\DestinationDir"
# Get list of files from source dir recursively. It doesn't list hidden files by default 
# Remove where{} if you don't need to exclude files by name, in this sample I exclude all README.md in any folders
$fileList = Get-ChildItem -Path $srcDirPath -File -Recurse | where{$_.Name -ne 'README.md'}
# get source dir path just in case to exactly match Get-ChildItem paths
$fullSrcDirPath = (Get-Item -Path $srcDirPath).FullName
foreach($file in $fileList)
{
    # build full destination file path
    $destFilePath = $destDirPath + $file.FullName.Remove(0, $fullSrcDirPath.Length)
    # proceed only if file doesn't exist in destination
    if(-not (Test-Path "$destFilePath"))
    {
        # Copy-Item can't create subfolders, so create subfolder if it doesn't exist
        # Get full destination folder path for current file
        $curDestDir = Split-Path $destFilePath -Parent
        if(-not (Test-Path "$curDestDir"))
        {
            # create subfolder(s)
            # $res here suppresses output
            $res = New-Item -Path "$curDestDir" -ItemType "directory"
        }
        Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination "$destFilePath"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something quick if you're worried about overwriting:

```
function mycopy { 
  if (! (test-path $args[1])) { copy $args[0] $args[1] } else { 'file exists' } 
}
```

Comment: This answer would benefit from an explanation of what the code does and how it solves OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't edit @Vasiliy Zverev answer. I made it a function and offered exclude list based on relative file pattern. What is good (relative to the approved answer) that it does it recursively.

```
function CpNoClobber ($srcDirPath,$destDirPath,$exclude)
{
    $fileList = Get-ChildItem -Path $srcDirPath  -File -Recurse 
# get source dir path just in case to exactly match Get-ChildItem paths
        $fullSrcDirPath = (Get-Item -Path $srcDirPath).FullName
        foreach($file in $fileList)
        {
            $rel= $file.FullName.Remove(0, $fullSrcDirPath.Length+1)
            $toexc= $exclude | %{ $rel -like  $_ } | Select-Object -First 1
            if ($toexc)
            {
                continue
            }
# build full destination file path
            $destFilePath = $destDirPath + $file.FullName.Remove(0, $fullSrcDirPath.Length)
# proceed only if file doesn't exist in destination
                if(-not (Test-Path "$destFilePath"))
                {
# Copy-Item can't create subfolders, so create subfolder if it doesn't exist
# Get full destination folder path for current file
                    $curDestDir = Split-Path $destFilePath -Parent
                        if(-not (Test-Path "$curDestDir"))
                        {
# create subfolder(s)
# $res here suppresses output
                            $res = New-Item -Path "$curDestDir" -ItemType "directory"
                        }
                    Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination "$destFilePath"
                    echo $file.FullName
                }
        }

}
```

Usage example:

```
CpNoClobber c:\temp c:\temp2 @("test\*")
```